# Erro when rbind data frame using data.table

Tags: r

I currently have the following two data frames which I am trying to merge together using the rbind() function, I run into a few errors when I try this, however with a very similar data.table I am able to apply the rbind() function with little problem;

DF1

```
> dput(head(budweiser_y1))
structure(list(IRI_KEY = c(234212L, 234212L, 234212L, 234212L, 
234212L, 234212L), WEEK = c(1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 1114L, 
1114L), SY = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), GE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), VEND = c(18200L, 18200L, 18200L, 18200L, 18200L, 18200L
), ITEM = c(106L, 106L, 106L, 16L, 16L, 16L), UNITS = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L), DOLLARS = c(9.98, 9.98, 9.98, 19.96, 19.96, 
19.96), F = c("NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE"), 
    D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), UPC = c(118216L, 118216L, 118216L, 118216L, 118216L, 
    118216L), L1 = c("CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", 
    "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", 
    "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID"
    ), L2 = c("DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", 
    "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", 
    "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH"
    ), L3 = c("ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", 
    "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC"
    ), L4 = c("ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", 
    "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC"
    ), L5 = c("BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", 
    "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER"), L9 = c("+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", 
    "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", 
    "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", 
    "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ"), VOL_EQ = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 
    0.25, 0.25, 0.25), VALNUM5 = c(72000L, 40000L, 72000L, 72000L, 
    40000L, 72000L), VALNUM6 = c(6000L, 1000L, 6000L, 6000L, 
    1000L, 6000L), VALNUM8 = c(72000L, 40000L, 72000L, 72000L, 
    40000L, 72000L), VALNUM9 = c(12000L, 40000L, 12000L, 12000L, 
    40000L, 12000L), ttlounces = c(72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L
    ), voleq = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25), packunits = c(6L, 
    1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L), ounce_per_bottle = c(12, 72, 12, 12, 
    72, 12), price_per_bottle = c(1.66, 9.98, 1.66, 3.33, 19.96, 
    3.33), price_per_ounce = c(0.138333333333333, 0.138611111111111, 
    0.138333333333333, 0.2775, 0.277222222222222, 0.2775)), .Names = c("IRI_KEY", 
"WEEK", "SY", "GE", "VEND", "ITEM", "UNITS", "DOLLARS", "F", 
"D", "PR", "UPC", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L9", "VOL_EQ", 
"VALNUM5", "VALNUM6", "VALNUM8", "VALNUM9", "ttlounces", "voleq", 
"packunits", "ounce_per_bottle", "price_per_bottle", "price_per_ounce"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000008350788>)
```

DF2

```
> dput(head(budweiser_y2))
structure(list(IRI_KEY = c(234212L, 234212L, 234212L, 234212L, 
234212L, 234212L), WEEK = c(1166L, 1166L, 1166L, 1166L, 1166L, 
1166L), SY = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), GE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), VEND = c(18200L, 18200L, 18200L, 18200L, 18200L, 18200L
), ITEM = c(466L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L), UNITS = c(5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L), DOLLARS = c(8.95, 4.99, 4.99, 4.99, 25.96, 25.96
), F = c("NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE"), D = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), PR = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), UPC = structure(c(5.84215827975315e-318, 
5.84064643887688e-319, 5.84064643887688e-319, 5.84064643887688e-319, 
5.84074525200605e-319, 5.84074525200605e-319), class = "integer64"), 
    L1 = c("CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", 
    "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", 
    "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID", "CATEGORY - BEER/ALE/ALCOHOLIC CID"
    ), L2 = c("DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", 
    "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", 
    "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH", "DOMESTIC BEER/ALE (INC NON-ALCOH"
    ), L3 = c("ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", 
    "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC"
    ), L4 = c("ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", 
    "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INC"
    ), L5 = c("BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER", 
    "BUDWEISER", "BUDWEISER"), L9 = c("+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 24OZ", 
    "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", 
    "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 72OZ", "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 96OZ", 
    "+BDWSR LAGER BEER CAN 96OZ"), VOL_EQ = c(0.0833, 0.25, 0.25, 
    0.25, 0.3333, 0.3333), VALNUM5 = c(24000L, 72000L, 40000L, 
    72000L, 96000L, 7000L), VALNUM6 = c(1000L, 6000L, 1000L, 
    6000L, 6000L, 1000L), VALNUM8 = c(24000L, 72000L, 40000L, 
    72000L, 96000L, 7000L), VALNUM9 = c(24000L, 12000L, 40000L, 
    12000L, 16000L, 7000L), ttlounces = c(24L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 
    96L, 96L), voleq = c(0.0833, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.3333, 0.3333
    ), packunits = c(1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L), ounce_per_bottle = c(24, 
    12, 72, 12, 16, 96), price_per_bottle = c(8.95, 0.83, 4.99, 
    0.83, 4.33, 25.96), price_per_ounce = c(0.372916666666667, 
    0.0691666666666667, 0.0693055555555556, 0.0691666666666667, 
    0.270625, 0.270416666666667)), .Names = c("IRI_KEY", "WEEK", 
"SY", "GE", "VEND", "ITEM", "UNITS", "DOLLARS", "F", "D", "PR", 
"UPC", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "L5", "L9", "VOL_EQ", "VALNUM5", 
"VALNUM6", "VALNUM8", "VALNUM9", "ttlounces", "voleq", "packunits", 
"ounce_per_bottle", "price_per_bottle", "price_per_ounce"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000008350788>)
```

I am trying to merge them using;

```
DF <- rbind(data.table(), budweiser_y1, budweiser_y2)
```

But I run into the following error;

```
Error in rbindlist(l, use.names, fill, idcol) : 
  Class attributes at column 12 of input list at position 3 does not match with column 12 of input list at position 2. Coercion of objects of class 'factor' alone is handled internally by rbind/rbindlist at the moment.
```

Searching online gives me very little, just that it could be a bug, are you able to row bind the DF´s?

Comment: why are you passing `data.table()` as the first argument?

Comment: I originally had `DF <- rbind(budweiser_y1, budweiser_y2)` which caused the same errors, I guess I just left it in when I wrote the post

Comment: The error is telling you that columns 12 are different. If you look at the `UPC` column, in one of the tables it's `int`, in the other it's `class integer64`. Fix this and it should work.

Comment: e.g., `budweiser_y2[, UPC := as.integer(UPC)]; rbind(budweiser_y1, budweiser_y2)` resolves it. But check the data is still correct (the original numbers look really small...)

Comment: That worked! and now the rbind() works, thanks!

Comment: checking `as.integer(budweiser_y2$UPC)` gave a `FALSE`result which was causing the error